# Should Chemical names be used at the start of sentences?

Tags: grammar, scientific-language

Which of the following sentences is more grammatically correct:

'Calcium was reported in the sample, but not Na.'

or

'Ca was reported in the sample, but not Na.'?

Or are they both fine?

Comment: Where are these sentences being used? If it's in a scientific paper then the use of chemical symbols would probably be acceptable. In more general publications, I would always spell out the chemical name.

Comment: @KillingTime In a doctoral thesis. In general, I would use the chemical symbol, but, I was unclear how to deal with the start of sentences.

Comment: What does „no Calcium“ even mean? Atomic Ca, Ca ions, Salts? If this is a unspecific Statement or which only works in context I would think using chemical symbols is a precision mismatch

Comment: It's a simple logical statement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about style choices in an esoteric domain.

Comment: In a doctoral thesis: ask your advisor.

Comment: There's no specific rule for abbreviations starting a sentence. There may be a convention in your field, and if so, you should have many papers that follow that convention. I find it hard to believe that people would spell out the name of complex molecules simply because they start a sentence. Something like "C17H21NO4 is fun at parties" would be unusual to see written out long hand.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, given that `scientific-language` is an approved tag within this group, can you explain why this question (specifically related to scientific language convention) is off-topic?

Comment: See Mitch's answer at [When science and English overlap, who wins?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11871/when-science-and-english-overlap-who-wins) (ie, which site, ELU or Chemistry, should you post a question on?) on ELU Meta. In my opinion, 'Na', which is given in both your examples, is not standard English. Fine, of course, in chemistry, but only where the prevailing style requirements (as in say a university science department style guide) specify that it is. Incidentally, my degrees are in chemistry.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I read the linked Q&A. Since I'm not looking for a technical definition (but rather my question was about written language), and following Mitch's logic, my question appears to be within the scope of this forum. Again, why have a `scientific language` tab if questions about scientific language conventions are off-topic?

Comment: No; Na is not used in everyday English. We've had questions like "Should it be 'two litres of sodium bicarbonate solution was added' or ' ... were added'?" Please allow others to have their own views on what is on-topic here and what should be on say Chemistry SE ('What are the practices to naming organic chemicals by abbreviations?' is a question there). I close-voted, as is allowed on ELU, for what I consider a valid reason (Ca and Na are used extremely rarely in non-science-domain writing, and asking whether it is correct to begin a sentence with say Ca is really peripheral)

Answer (score 8):

If you use the word for the first element, it reads much better if you also use it for the second one.

> Calcium was reported in the sample, but not sodium.

If you clearly indicate the symbols of the elements in the previous text, like calcium (Ca), sodium (Na), then you can use only symbols in the following text.

> Ca was reported in the sample, but not Na.

Even in scientific texts, they don't usually use just symbols when elements are mentioned for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The first one looks much better. I was taught not to abbreviate terms that appear fewer than three times after their first use, also that a sentence should not begin with an abbreviation. However, I would accept the second in an informal/technical context, such as a laboratory note, because it simply reads faster for a reader who's into the subject.

Comment: If you're writing a thesis with lots of chemical elements in it, you shouldn't abbreviate only the ones you use more than four times.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think its OK to mix element names and abbreviations (except in beginning a sentence where the full name should be used). It may seem a bit informal, but some useful reasons are;

a) Avoids using the same words more than once in a sentence i.e. improving grammar, readability (and adding variety).

b) As a symbol alternates the use of the full term, using a full element name can provide additional emphasis at a particular point in the narrative, such as for important findings and/or power statements.

c) Impresses the memory that e.g. Bismuth/Bi (in the sense they are used) are interchangeably one and the same.

d) Very occasionally both terms may be used together for even more emphasis, particularly for very important findings.